# 2D array inquiries

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, array, time-limit-exceeded

**I am trying to solve a problem as described below:**

> You are given an input of a n*m forest.
>
> You have to answer a group of inquiries. Your task is to return the
>   number of trees for every inquiry.
>
> **Input**: In the first line you are given 3 integers; n,m and q. This means that the size of the forest is n×m squares and the number of
>   inquiries is q.
>
> Then you get n rows that describe the forest. Every square is either
>   blank (.) or a tree (*).
>
> Then you are given q lines of inquiries. Every line has 4 integers y1,
>   x1, y2 and x2, that define the area.
>
> **Output**: Return the number of trees in the inquired area.
>
> **Limits**:
>
> 1≤n,m≤1000
>
> 1≤q≤10^5
>
> 1≤y1≤y2≤n
>
> 1≤x1≤x2≤m
>
> **Example:**
>
> Input:
>
> ```
>    4 7 3
>
>    .*...*.
>
>    **..*.*
>
>    .**.*..
>
>    ......*
>
>    1 1 2 2
>
>    3 2 4 7
>
>    2 5 2 5
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
>    3
>
>    4
>
>    1
> ```

My code is below; first it initializes the array so that every square is initialized to the number of trees in the rectangle from the top left square to the square. That takes O(n^2). After that I am able to answer the inquiries in O(1).

```
firstline = input().split()

rownumber = int(firstline[0]) #How many rows
rowlength = int(firstline[1]) #How many columns
numberOfInquiries = int(firstline[2])

forest = []

def printOut(someList):
    for x in range(0, len(someList)):
        print(someList[x])
#This function exist just for debugging

for x in range(0, rownumber):
    forest.append([])
    UI = list(input())
    if UI[0] == ".":
        first = 0
    else:
        first = 1
    forest[x].append(first)
    for y in range(1, rowlength):
        if UI[y] == "*":
            forest[x].append(int(forest[x][y-1])+1)
        else:
            forest[x].append(int(forest[x][y-1]))

for column in range(0, rowlength):
    for row in range(1, rownumber):
        forest[row][column] += forest[row-1][column]

print("")
#Everything is initialized






for x in range(0, numberOfInquiries):
    UI = input().split()
    y1 = int(UI[0])-1
    x1 = int(UI[1])-1
    y2 = int(UI[2])-1
    x2 = int(UI[3])-1
    first = forest[y2][x2]
    second = forest[y1-1][x2]
    third = forest[y2][x1-1]
    fourth = forest[y1-1][x1-1]
    if x1 == 0:
        third = 0
        fourth = 0
    if y1 == 0:
        second = 0
        fourth = 0
    print(first-second-third+fourth)
```

My question remains: how can this be optimized? The initialization takes 0.7-0.8 s in the larger cases and answering the inquiries also takes about the same. This is about 50% too slow for the largest test cases (time limit =1s). Are those just too much for Python? Most of the people solving these problems use C++.

Comment: What challenge is this?

Comment: A training problem from the Finnish Olympiad in Informatics page. https://cses.fi/problemset/. This problem is only available in Finnish, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can use `map` or a list comprehension to allow placing assignment to `rownumber`, `rowlength` and `numberOfInquiries` on the same line:

   ```
   rownumber, rowlength, numberOfInquiries = map(int, input().split())
   ```
2. When using `range` you don't have to specify `0`. `range(rownumber)` works fine.
3. I find it hard to understand both reading from input and mutating it at the same time. You may want to build the forest of input before doing any mutations.

   ```
   forrest = (
       input()
       for _ in range(rownumber)
   )
   ```
4. You can abuse Booleans as they subclass ints, `issubclass(bool, int)`, and so you can just use `first = UI[0] == '*'`.
5. You can use `itertools.accumulate`, so that you don't have to perform your `y` loop.
6. If you swap your loops when adding the previous row to the next you can use the `pairwise` recipe.

   ```
   for prev, curr in pairwise(forest):
       for column in range(rowlength):
           curr[column] += prev[column]
   ```
7. Follow PEP 8, and use `snake_case`, rather than `TitleCase` or `lowercase`.

And so I'd use:

```
import itertools

row_number, row_length, number_of_inquiries = map(int, input().split())


def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


forest = [
    list(itertools.accumulate(
        item == "*" for item in row
    ))
    for row in (
        input()
        for _ in range(row_number)
    )
]

for prev, curr in pairwise(forest):
    for column in range(row_length):
        curr[column] += prev[column]


for x in range(number_of_inquiries):
    y1, x1, y2, x2 = (int(i) - 1 for i in input().split())
    first = forest[y2][x2]
    second = forest[y1-1][x2]
    third = forest[y2][x1-1]
    fourth = forest[y1-1][x1-1]
    if x1 == 0:
        third = 0
        fourth = 0
    if y1 == 0:
        second = 0
        fourth = 0
    print(first-second-third+fourth)
```

---

Since you need to squeeze another 0.2 seconds, you could try setting the [`flush` argument](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#print) to print to `False`, to see if flushing is the limiting factor. This would look like:

```
print(first-second-third+fourth, flush=False)
```

Alternately you can do this yourself by not calling `print`.

```
ret = ''
for x in range(number_of_inquiries):
    y1, x1, y2, x2 = (int(i) - 1 for i in input(ret).split())
    # ...
    ret = first-second-third+fourth
```

Comment: Nope, still exceeding the time limit. Thanks for all your helpful tips, though.

Comment: You cut down the time by about 0.5 seconds. Just needs 0.2 off, it is very close!

Comment: @Kurns you could probably do that by using `input` as `print`. `ret = ''; for x in ... input(ret) ... ret = first-second-third+fourth`

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't really understand.

Comment: @Kurns I've added what I mean to my answer, if this isn't fast enough, then I suggest that you add a profile of your code. This means that I won't be guessing at what the problem is, and will be able to focus on making what is slow faster

Comment: Setting flush to False actually slows this down by about 0.05 s. I think profiling is the only solution left.

Comment: @Kurns Did you try the other way too? And yeah, if you post that then I may be able to help you out. Otherwise, Python's not the right tool for the job. Or we have some mad micro optimisations to do

Comment: I did some profiling and realized that this problem cannot be solved fast enough with Python. In some cases this script takes up to 1.6 s. Guess C++ would be the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

I like the pre-initialisation approach.

One thing that you should look into is replacing explicit lists and `append` with approaches that operate on lists directly. List or generator comprehensions should be your go to tool for many things.

For example looking at this block of code

```
    UI = list(input())
    if UI[0] == ".":
        first = 0
    else:
        first = 1
    forest[x].append(first)
    for y in range(1, rowlength):
        if UI[y] == "*":
            forest[x].append(int(forest[x][y-1])+1)
        else:
            forest[x].append(int(forest[x][y-1]))
```

We can map the dots and stars to zero and one:

```
UI = list(input())
forest_line = [1 if x == "*" else 0 for x in UI]
```

Python has a useful bunch of built in functions in the itertools module, and in particular [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) gives the prefix sums in a list. You'd need to import it at the start of the script.

```
forest[x] = accumulate(forest_line)
```

We can even collapse all this together. Here nothing gets assigned to a list until the very end, which makes things faster by avoiding storing the intermediate values.

```
forest[x] = list(accumulate(1 if x == "*" else 0 for x in input()))
```

You will generally find that this style of coding works faster than explicitely looping and appending, and is considered more readable by python enthusiasts.
(Although there is a limit to how much you can cram into one line before it becomes too much of a labyrinth)